# Breeze "property is required" EF 6.1.3 when no required attribute

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

After updating from EF 6.1.1 to 6.1.3, breeze started doing this on one of my properties.

Here's the object structure :

```
public class Class1
{
    public virtual string myProperty { get; set; }
    // other properties 
}

public class Class2 : Class1
{
    // other properties 
}

public class Class3 : Class1
{
    [Required]
    public override string myProperty { get; set; }
    // other properties 
}
```

I'm creating a "Class2" object in breeze and trying to save it. I'm not setting "myProperty" anywhere, there's no input linked to it at all as its not needed on this page. When I save changes I get a message saying "myProperty is required".

Rolling back to EF 6.1.1, everything works good but I ran that update for other purposes.

EDIT : I see that there's is a nullable:false in my metadata on "Class1" for the property after the update to 6.1.3. I can easily assume that the problem is there but why is that generated and how to avoid it, strings are nullable by default technically.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it does not depend on Breeze.

**EF 6.1.3**
It happens exactly what you write and for me is a BUG on EF.
I used this model/context/test to reproduce the error

```
public class Class1
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string MyProperty { get; set; }
    // other properties 
}

public class Class3 : Class1
{
    [Required]
    public override string MyProperty { get; set; }

    public string Class3Prop { get; set; }
}


public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public TestContext(DbConnection connection) : base(connection, true) { }

    public DbSet<Class1> C1s { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Class3> C3s { get; set; }

}

    public static void Run(DbConnection connection)
    {
        using (TestContext db = new TestContext(connection))
        {
            // MyProperty not specified
            db.C1s.Add(new Class1());
            db.SaveChanges();   // Here in EF 6.1.3 is raised an exception because MyProperty is required but we did not mark it as Required
        }
    }
```

The database contains only 1 table (and __MigrationHistory of course).

dbo.Class1(Id autoincrement, MyProperty varchar not null, Class3Prop varchar null, Discriminator varchar not null).

so with we will never be able to insert a null MyProperty.

**EF 6.1.1**
Everything's working as expected.
Adding C1 works, Adding C3 (without setting MyProperty) does not work.

The database contains the same table as above but MyProperty is nullable.

**OTHER CONSIDERATION about 6.1.3**
Configuring it via fluent interface the behavior does not change.
Also, if in Class1 you specify MaxLength 30 and in Class3 specify 15 the field will be varchar 15.
For me is definitely an EF 6.1.3 bug (I posted it on CodePlex)

Comment: I did not answer to your question. You could try to configure it via fluent interface (I make some other tests then I'll do it)